# I am having problem creating a unit test in python. can anyone let me know what's my mistake?

Tags: python

Someone help me out with this problem. I was able to run the cars.py file but for some reason I dont know how to properly make a unit test with a value that has been read from csv file.

### CSV file content:

```
Car Name,Price
Toyota Camry,28000
Lexus,35000
Range Rover,75000
Volswagen Beetle,32000
Audi A5,55000
Jeep,52000
Toyota RAV4,48000
Nissan Ultima,29500
Aston Martin,85000
```

### cars.py content

```
import csv
import math
def expensive_Car(expensiveCar):
    with open('Cars.csv', "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
        header = next(reader)
        line_count = 0
        expensiveCarCompany= 0

        for row in reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                line_count+=1
            
            else:
                line_count+=1
                     
            #Finding the most expensive car
            if int(row[1]) > expensiveCar:
                expensiveCarCompany, expensiveCar = row[0], int(row[1]) 
           
    print(f'Expensive car company: {expensiveCarCompany} which is ${expensiveCar}.')    
    return expensiveCarCompany, expensiveCar 

def cheapest_Car(cheapestCar):
    with open('Cars.csv', "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
        header = next(reader)
    
        line_count = 0
        cheapestCarCompany = 0
        for row in reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                line_count+=1
            
            else:
                line_count+=1
            
            #Finding the most cheapest car
            if int(row[1]) < cheapestCar:
                cheapestCarCompany, cheapestCar = row[0], int(row[1])
     
    print(f'Cheapest car company: {cheapestCarCompany} which is ${cheapestCar}.')
    return cheapestCarCompany, cheapestCar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cheapCar = cheapest_Car(math.inf)
    priceyCar = expensive_Car(-math.inf)
```

##Unittest content##

```
import unittest
import cars
class test_carPrice(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_ExpensiveCar(self):
        result = cars.expensive_Car(self)
        self.assertEquals(result, 85000)
    
    def test_CheapestCar(self):
        self.assertIs(cars.cheapest_Car, 28000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This is the first time learning python and I don't know what I did wrong but it keeps on showing me these errors.

```
##Error message from cars.py :##
'>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'test_carPrice'

##error message from unittest##
<function cheapest_Car at 0x000002013B511240> is not 28000
in test_CheapestCar self.assertIs(cars.cheapest_Car, 28000)
```

Comment: 1. You forgot to call the `cheapest_Car` function.  2. You should use `assertEquals` to compare numbers, not `assertIs`.  3. `cheapest_Car` returns a 2-tuple, but you are trying to compare it against a single value.  Putting these together you should have: `self.assertEquals(cars.cheapest_Car()[1], 28000)`

Comment: Also just a note regarding general best practices: You should not rely on a "real" data file in your unit test.  Unit tests are meant to verify the *behavior* of your code, not look for *specific values* in your data.  For example if you ever add more cheap/expensive cars in your input file, your unit tests might suddenly break, even though your code still works!  One option would be to create a fake CSV file containing some test data and structure your code in such a way that you can read from that fake CSV when in a unit test.

Comment: What did you intend to achieve by passing `self` (which is a TestCase) to `cars.expensive_Car` (which expects an integer) in the line `result = cars.expensive_Car(self)`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods don't need a parameter, as the method is the one finding the cheapest or more expensive car, it is not something you give to the method.

In you tests you should have called them the same, with `math.inf`, and call the method, because `cars.cheapest_Car` is the function itself, and you can't compare it to an int

Tests become

```
def test_ExpensiveCar(self):
    company, value = expensive_Car()
    self.assertEquals(value, 85000)

def test_CheapestCar(self):
    company, value = cheapest_Car()
    self.assertEquals(value, 28000)
```

---

And with better namings you have

```
def expensive_car():
    with open('Cars.csv', "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        next(reader)
        expensive_car_company = 0
        expensive_car = -math.inf

        for row in reader:
            if int(row[1]) > expensive_car:
                expensive_car_company, expensive_car = row[0], int(row[1])

    print(f'Expensive car company: {expensive_car_company} which is ${expensive_car}.')
    return expensive_car_company, expensive_car
```

Comment: it is still showing me error after testing everything from here. I just want to get the value from cars.csv. For eg. cheapest car is 28000, so I want to get that value from cars.py as an argument in unittest file and assertEqual with 28000. But for some reason it doesn't get the value from cars.py module

Comment: cheapest_Car() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cheapestCar'

Comment: @Skitpo remove the parameter of the method. As I explained and showed for `expensive_car` . Also you need to understand it, if you'd have you'd have solve that yourself